# Quantifiers in the definition of unions of collection (Halmos)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Halmos's *Naive Set Theory*, Section 5 on Complements and Powers, he puts forth that as immediate consequences of De Morgan's laws and the definitions of the union and intersection, the following equivalencies hold:

$$\left({\bigcup}_{x\in \mathscr C}X\right)' = {\bigcap}_{x\in \mathscr C}X'$$
and that
$$\left({\bigcap}_{x\in \mathscr C}X\right)' = {\bigcup}_{x\in \mathscr C}X'$$

This makes intuitive sense, but when I'm trying to work through the proofs, I am not confident that I'm using quantifiers correctly.

In the case of the first argument, I would think of the complement of the union of collection $\mathscr C$ as "The complement of the set of x such that there exists some set X such that X is in $\mathscr C$ and x is in X." So I would formulate it thusly:

$$(\exists X [(X \in \mathscr C) \land (x \in X)])' $$
$$\not\exists X [(X \in \mathscr C) \land (x \in X)]$$
$$\forall X \lnot[(X \in \mathscr C) \land (x \in X)]$$
$$\forall X[\lnot(X \in \mathscr C) \lor \lnot(x \in X)]$$
$$\forall X[(X \not\in \mathscr C) \lor (x \not\in X)]$$

This seems to line up with the definition of ${\bigcap}_{x\in \mathscr C}X'$ as I understand it, but I feel certain I've overlooked something, or that my understanding of how to describe sets in logical notation is completely mistaken from the ground up. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The usual way to prove them is to show reciprocal inclusion... $x \in \left({\bigcup}_{X\in \mathscr C}X\right)'$ iff $x \notin ({\bigcup}_{X\in \mathscr C}X)$. But to say that $x$ does not belongs to ... means that : $\forall X \in \mathscr C (x \notin X)$, i.e. $\forall X \in \mathscr C (x \in X')$

Answer (score 2):

I'll call the five lines after your "thusly" (1)-(5). (2)-(5) are pairwise equivalent and (5) is equivalent to
$$\forall X(X \in \mathscr{C} \rightarrow x \in X') \tag{6}$$ which is in turn equivalent to $$x \in \bigcap_{X \in \mathscr{C}} X' \tag{7}$$ So that part is fine.

On the other hand, (1) is ill-formed: you're trying to take the complement of a formula, but formulas are not sets and do not have complements. So that line just doesn't mean anything. Similarly $A \Rightarrow (A \cap B)$ does not mean anything. Things like this are not sentences, any more than "If it rains tomorrow, then Scarlett Johansson" is a sentence: you're putting names where sentences should be, or sentences where names should be.

So, replace (1) with the following:
\begin{gather}
x \in \left(\bigcup_{X \in \mathscr C} X\right)' \tag{1'} \\[12pt]
\neg \left(x \in \bigcup_{X \in \mathscr C} X\right) \tag{1''}
\end{gather}
Now (1'), (1'') and (2)-(7) are all equivalent to each other. In particular (1') and (7) are equivalent to each other, which means that the first equality in your post holds. As a method of proof, this is fine.